# How to create a new deployment and service in kubernetes using Gradle pugin (or task)

Tags: gradle, kubernetes

I see there are many Github pages for gradle kubernetes plugin like 
https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-kubernetes-plugin

https://github.com/kolleroot/gradle-kubernetes-plugin

https://github.com/qaware/gradle-cloud-deployer
None of these having any concrete example **how to connect to kubernetes from gradle and create a new deployment and service** 
 I tried all about git link in gradle but no luck...

Answer (score 2):

Since I also faced a lack of plugins that deal with Kubernetes I started working on a Gradle plugin to make deploying resources to a Kubernetes cluster easier: https://github.com/kuberig-io/kuberig.

In the user manual you will find details about how to connect to a kubernetes cluster here:
https://kuberig-io.github.io/kuberig/#/initializing-an-environment

It also includes an example of how to define a deployment here: https://kuberig-io.github.io/kuberig/#/defining-a-deployment
And a service here:
https://kuberig-io.github.io/kuberig/#/defining-a-service

It may also be useful to go through the quickstart first https://kuberig-io.github.io/kuberig/#/quick-start.

Hope it can be of use to you.